# Sending generated XML file via SFTP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've generated an XML file using tsql and I'm wondering if there's any way to send it to a remote server via SFTP. Is there any way to do it without external software? What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Any tips will be greatly appreciated

edit:

I forgot to mention that I need a new copy of the file on the server everyday, so...

I need to generate a new file everyday and then replace the old file on the remote server.

I've tried setting up a JOB that runs a SSIS package and it partly does the job, but the standard package doesn't support SFTP. :(

Comment: Natively with SQL Server? No. You could use SSIS, but that only supports FTP out of the box, so you'll need to use a CLI call to *something else* to still send the file. Personally I use PSFTP. This question is too broad on it's own though.

Comment: The best approach is to *use external software*. SQL Server is a database server, it doesn't handle files and file transfers. Just install OpenSSH on the server [if it doesn't already have it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) and use the `sftp` command. For periodic export jobs you can create a SQL Agent job that exports the data and then copies them with `sftp`, or you can create an SSIS package whose last step runs `sftp`

Comment: You can execute a command-line task in SSIS and run the `sftp` command

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with SSIS, you could use a PowerShell script scheduled via a SQL Agent job. The PS script could invoke the `WinSCP.com` CLI or use the .NET `WinSCPnet.dll` assembly for the SFTP transfer and handle the file management per your needs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos

I managed to solve it using command line task in SSIS, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it using WinSCP & command line task in SSIS as suggested by user
 [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)